# Why am I not getting any time difference before and after for loop in CPP?

Tags: c++, for-loop, time, c++-chrono

I am trying to figure out time difference between iterative and recursive function but I am not able to even find out difference between for loop. Anyone has any idea about this ??

```
int main (){
    //int arr[7] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    ll arr[100000];
    unsigned __int64 one = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    for (ll i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        arr[i]=i+1; 
    }
    unsigned __int64 two = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    // int a=binSearchRecursive(arr,6755,0,10000);
    // int b=binSearchIter(arr,6755,0,10000);
    // unsigned __int64 three = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    cout << "Recursive :"<< one << " " <<two <<endl;
    cout << "Iterative :" <<two-one << std :: endl;
    // cout <<a<<" " << b  ;
    return 0;
}
```

Output -

```
Recursive :1635504404011 1635504404011
Recursive :0
```

I just added 2nd loop to replace existing values

```
int main (){
    //int arr[7] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    ll arr[100000];
    unsigned __int64 one = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    for (ll i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        arr[i]=i*3; 
    }
    for (long long i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        arr[i]=arr[i]*arr[i+1]; 
    }
    unsigned __int64 two = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    // int a=binSearchRecursive(arr,6755,0,10000);
    // int b=binSearchIter(arr,6755,0,10000);
    // unsigned __int64 three = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    //cout << "Recursive :"<< one << " " <<two <<endl;
    cout << "Recursive :"<< two-one <<endl;
    //int b = arr[23423] + arr[73432];
    //cout << "Iterative :" << three- two << std :: endl;
    // cout <<a<<" " << b  ;
    return 0;
}
```

Now I am getting output as -

```cpp
Recursive :1029000
```

So which difference is this ?? Is it for both loops or just for 1st ??

Comment: The whole loop is probably optimized away.

Comment: Don't benchmark your code like that, it's very unreliable. Use this: https://www.quick-bench.com/

Comment: @pptaszni thanks for the website but I wanna know what's happening here? I will use quick bench afterward

Comment: @TedLyngmo What do you mean by optimized ??? can you elaborate ??

Comment: The compiler can see that you don't use `arr` anywhere, so it decides not to run this loop.

Comment: @ykaner so if i just simple read / write in array after the loop will it work ??

Comment: Yes, you can trick the compiler by adding a print of `i`, so it will be compiled and run the loop. If you compiling with gcc you can add `-O0` flag to say the compiler not to optimize.

Comment: @ykaner i just added `int b = arr[23423] + arr[73432];` this after loop but its still not working

Comment: The `for`-loop may have a sub-millisecond duration. If the machine could do (e.g.) a billion of those operations per second, which is well possible, 100000 steps would take a tenth of a millisecond. Which may give you a 1 in 10 probability of the millisecond count actually flipping. (That is, unless a compiler in an `-O<huge N>` mode optimizes the loop away entirely; that would reduce the probability to  near zero.) Recommendations: (1) Pick nanoseconds as a unit and look how that works. (2) Do *something* (e.g. compute a sum and print it out) with the array after the measurement.

Comment: @Spartex If the compiler can figure out what will be in `arr[23423]` and `arr[73432]` already at compile time, it can _still_  skip doing the actual loop in runtime and just put the sum of those in `b` already at compile time. The optimizers in modern compilers are _brutal_.

Comment: @TedLyngmo but how will it figure out `arr[23423]`and `arr[73432]` without going through loop ?

Comment: Might be worth reading about the ["as-if" rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).  Specifically: `"Allows any and all code transformations that do not change the observable behavior of the program"`.

Comment: @Spartex I can already tell you that `arr[23423]` is `23424` and `arr[73432]` is `73433` without computing the other hundred thousand entries, and compilers are better at arithmetic than I am.

Comment: @Spartex it's `constexpr`-capable code. Essentially it unwrapped the loop and what you had told it, that  `arr[x] := x+1`. Compiler can do that as per as-if rule. In some cases this may lead to unexpected (e.g. reading beyond end of array would produce correct result, because it's an UB)

Comment: another thing, `system_clock` may go backward or do unexpected. you probably have to use stable. Use `steady_clock`. ANd milliseconds too small a unit here. Those operations today are nanoseconds.

Comment: @Spartex [example using `steady_clock`](https://godbolt.org/z/j6K3r35rG) - Look at the assembly. It only does two `call    std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock::now()` after eachother and no loop in between. That takes  < 200 ns. If you uncomment the two lines at the bottom the time will likely increase a lot - but it doesn't have to if the compiler is clever.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie what should i do to force it to go through loop ?

Comment: Use the quick-bench link you got at the top

Comment: @TedLyngmo I wanna do that manually this time.

Comment: Put some random data in the array before starting the test and do some calculations on that data in the loop - and print some result depending on the content of the array afterwards. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/6cdj94av7)

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the compiler is optimizing the loop away. Usually you'd disable optimizations, but if you don't want to outright disable it, you can add the `volatile` keyword to your variable `arr` and you will notice a huge speed difference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    volatile long long arr[100000];
    auto one = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    for (long long i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = i * 3;
    }
    for (long long i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i] * arr[i + 1];
    }
    auto two = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();

    cout << "Recursive :" << two - one << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My result on MSVC 2019 with all optimizations enabled:

```
Recursive :88800
```

The `volatile` keyword tells the compiler not to optimize a variable, in any way.

Comment: I just used `volatile` keyword before `arr` as you told and my output changed from 99600 to 0 . Can you explain this please ?

Comment: Which example are you talking about?

Comment: the one you gave

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @A.Smolaik MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1

Answer (score -2):

it's optimized.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <execution>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <atomic>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long long  arr[100000];
    auto t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    for (long long i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        arr[i]=i*3; 
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::chrono::nanoseconds f =  std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2 - t1);
    std::cout  << f.count() << std::endl;
    

    return 0;

}
```

`c++ -std=c++17 -O3 'first 3.cpp'  -ltbb -lpthread -o t`

Comment: I am running your code in vs code and it's still giving me output of 0 nanoseconds.

Comment: @Spartex 319 in both cases. ubuntu

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин at least it wasn't АстраЛинукс

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie 0 here means that ns timing is not supported by os. route it to your brothers

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин with steady_clock? That means that two points of time were divided by time period lesser than  minimal resolution (which is not defined by standard), but available resolution can depend on used runtime library on some OSes. But system_clock may experience time travel, even backward, because it may rely on so called real time clock. `steady_clock` may have better result, but keyword is "may", may also have worse resolution.  That's implementation details. There is no ISO standard interface for monotonic available on Linux because it is unique to those systems.

Comment: Unrelated: There's a nice tool called `include-what-you-use` (yes, that's the actual command - it's terrible but easy to remember). It can help to remove unused headers and suggest the addition of headers implicitly used.